# How can I access controller in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to access controller in angular directive. How can I do that?

I have a link function in the directive and I want to access the controller passed to the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link function's 4th parameter gives you access to the controller instance.

```
return {
            template: template,
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'myCtrl', 
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {}
         };
```